# Need a hint to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} {\sin(x)+\sin(3x)+\sin(5x) \over \tan(2x)+\tan(4x)+\tan(6x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I know that $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 4\cos({A \over 2})\cos({B \over 2})\cos({C \over 2})$ when $A+B+C=\pi$. If ${x \to 0}$ then I have a half circle, right?
If it is right then I have

$\tan(2x) + \tan(4x) + \tan(6x)=\tan(2x)\tan(4x)\tan(6x)$.

I got stuck at
$${4\cos({x \over 2})\cos({3x \over 2})\cos({5x \over 2}) \over \tan(2x)\tan(4x)\tan(6x)}$$

Is this correct? Do you have a hint to help me?

Comment: The limit in your question can be evaluated by dividing the numerator and denominator by $x$ and then evaluating each separately.

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule also works here pretty easily. Of course, that is just another way of doing what @AbhishekParab suggested, but you may be more familiar with it.

Comment: @AbhishekParab I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} {\sin(x)+\sin(3x)+\sin(5x) \over \tan(2x)+\tan(4x)+\tan(6x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} {\cos(x)+3\cos(3x)+5\cos(5x) \over 2\sec^2(2x)+4\sec^2(4x)+6\sec^2(6x)} = \frac{9}{12} = \frac{3}{4}$$

I used L'Hopital's rule

Comment: I haven't learned L'Hopital's rule but it is a good way to solve it.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computation. In essence it is equivalent to Taylor at order $1$, but doesn't work if numerator and denominator doesn't have limit $0$ or $\infty$ (in particular if one of them doesn't have a limit at all).

Answer (score 3):

In what follows I will provide full details of the idea of Abhishek Parab.
First divide top and bottom by $x,$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x}{\tan 2x+\tan 4x+\tan 6x} &=&\frac{\left( 
\dfrac{\sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x}{x}\right) }{\left( \dfrac{\tan 2x+\tan
4x+\tan 6x}{x}\right) } \\
&& \\
&=&\frac{\left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x}+3\left( \dfrac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right)
+5\left( \dfrac{\sin 5x}{5x}\right) \right) }{\left( 2\left( \dfrac{\tan 2x}{%
2x}\right) +4\left( \dfrac{\tan 4x}{4x}\right) +6\left( \dfrac{\tan 6x}{6x}%
\right) \right) }
\end{eqnarray*}
Now using the standard limits
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan u}{u}=1
\end{equation*}
the limit follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x}{\tan 2x+\tan 4x+\tan 6x}
&=&\frac{\left( \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}+3\left(
\lim\limits_{3x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right) +5\left(
\lim\limits_{5x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin 5x}{5x}\right) \right) }{\left(
2\left( \lim\limits_{2x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\tan 2x}{2x}\right) +4\left(
\lim\limits_{4x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\tan 4x}{4x}\right) +6\left(
\lim\limits_{6x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\tan 6x}{6x}\right) \right) } \\
&=& \\
&=&\frac{\left( 1+3\left( 1\right) +5\left( 1\right) \right) }{\left(
2\left( 1\right) +4\left( 1\right) +6\left( 1\right) \right) }=\frac{3}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

With *Taylor's formula* at order $1$:

$\sin x+\sin 3x +\sin 5x= x+3x+5x+o(x)$, $\,\tan 2x +\tan 4x +\tan 6x=2x+4x+6x+o(x)$, whence:
$$\frac{\sin x+\sin 3x +\sin 5x}{\tan 2x +\tan 4x +\tan 6x}=\frac{9x+o(x)}{12x+o(x)}=\frac{9+o(1)}{12+o(1)}\to \frac34$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a much simpler take on this question and it uses the following result $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x = 0\tag{1}$$ from which we get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\cos x = 1\tag{2}$$ using the relation $\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}x = 1$. Further dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$ we get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\tan x = 0\tag{3}$$ We can see that the numerator $f(x)$ of the given expression can be simplified as
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sin x + \sin 3x + \sin 5x\notag\\
&= \sin x + \sin 5x + \sin 3x\notag\\
&= 2\sin 3x\cos 2x + \sin 3x\notag\\
&= \sin 3x(2\cos 2x + 1)\notag
\end{align}
and the denominator $g(x)$ can be simplified as
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \tan 2x + \tan 4x + \tan 6x\notag\\
&= \tan 6x(1 - \tan 2x\tan 4x) + \tan 6x\notag\\
&= \tan 6x(2 - \tan 2x\tan 4x)\notag\\
\end{align} In the above we have used the formula $$\tan(a + b) = \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1 - \tan a\tan b}$$ which can be rewritten as $$\tan a + \tan b = \tan(a + b)(1 - \tan a\tan b)$$
Hence the desired limit $L$ can be calculated as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 3x(2\cos 2x + 1)}{\tan 6x(2 - \tan 2x\tan 4x)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 3x}{\tan 6x}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\cos 2x + 1}{2 - \tan 2x\tan 4x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 3x (1 - \tan^{2}3x)}{2\tan 3x}\cdot\frac{2\cdot 1 + 1}{2 - 0\cdot 0}\notag\\
&= \frac{3}{4}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 3x}{\tan 3x}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}(1 - \tan^{2}3x)\notag\\
&= \frac{3}{4}\lim_{x \to 0}\cos 3x\cdot (1 - 0\cdot 0)\notag\\
&= \frac{3}{4}\cdot 1 = \frac{3}{4}\notag
\end{align}
The calculation above has been presented in somewhat unnecessarily detailed fashion to highlight the fact that no other limits other than $(1), (2), (3)$ are used in the process and as mentioned before out of these the result $(1)$ is the fundamental one. Thus there is no need to invoke the slightly more powerful result $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I see this yesterday. I would like to point that your solution here (and in the other post) do not use ''the powerful result'' so it is powerful. On the other hand, it uses ''some'' trigonometric identities. My solution here (and those of others in the other post) uses the powerful result but do not use any trigonometric identity. It is to say that both solutions are nice, and each one have its strong-side and its weak-side. Thank you, I learned this (your) solution from you.

Comment: @Idris: If this was a test probably I would use the method which requires least effort in writing and has very less scope of calculation mistake. Thus method based on $(\sin x)/x$ would be the preferred one. But here while solving limit problems on MSE my focus is to reduce the problem via algebraic manipulation to the simplest results in calculus. That's you will find my answers a bit long and perhaps unsuitable for student in exam. But solving these problems I learn that many seemingly complex limit problems are in essence very simple.

Comment: @Idris: In case you mention such methods to your students, you should mention their unsuitability for competitive exams.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as $x \to 0$, the numerator goes as $x + 3x + 5x$ at leading order, whereas the denominator behaves like $2x+4x+6x$, for which we have: $L =(1+3+5)/(2+4+6) = 3/4$.

I have used the well-known property $\sin{x} \sim x$ as $x \to 0$.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: This is dangerous, as equivalence of functions is *not* compatible with addition.

Comment: Indeed! I think your answer is more rigorous in that regard. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Intuitively, your answer is OK (we all think like that, because in the background, we see Taylor's formula),  I would say it's more striking, but it's dangerous to give it as a model for novices, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with you, @Bernard, I just wanted to give the OP a quick (and intuitive) alternative to solve her problem. I have a question: why do you use little O in your answer instead of big O?

Comment: *Taylor-Young*'s formula at order $n$ uses only $o(x^n)$. You need *Taylor-Lagrange*'s version to have  $O(x^{n+1})$. Most of the time – in any case for limits computations, Taylor-Young is enough.